# HTML5 - develop pluginable application

Tags: javascript, html, plugins

I want to develop an HTML5 cross platform application. I am completely new in this web applications deal,  so I need some guidance to how to start....
I want to write an applications that looks very similiar to the startup Windows8 page whitch display all the meto applications. My app will display a 5 windows to the user and the user has to choose one of them.
My questions are:

1. If I want to wrote this windows as plugins, so it will be easy to extend my app and add additional windows - how do I have to write it? can someone please able to guide me a little?
2. Is there and common desigh pattern to HTML5+javascript applications?

I will appriciate any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default there is no common pattern for developing website/application in HTML/Javascript. Either you have to build everything from scratch or use one of the frameworks that is available.

To list a few

1. [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)
2. [Ember](http://emberjs.com/)
3. [Angular](http://angularjs.org/)
4. [Sproutcore](http://sproutcore.com/)

If you want build a single page application with desktop like interface **Sproutcore** is recommended. 
demos : http://showcase.sproutcore.com/#demos/Creating%20Playful%20Interfaces